# Java Stream Manipulations

Tags: java, stream, iostream

I am modifying some existing java code which currently uses the following process:

1. Opens a FileInputStream to read a file from disk.
2. Passes the FileInputStream into the constructor for a DataInputStream
3. Reads the data from the DataInputStream into a byte array
4. Creates an Apache Commons ByteArrayPartSource based on the byte array
5. Creates an Apache Commons FilePart based on the ByteArrayPartSource.
6. Creates an Apache Commons MultipartRequestEntity based on the FilePart.
7. Calls an external API that requires the MultipartRequestEntity as its parameter.

I'm trying to modify this process by adding code to scan the input file and search/replace a text string. For example, it might scan the file for pattern 'abc' and replace it with 'xyz'. However, I'm not sure which step I should add this modification to. Is there any performance implication about which step I pick? Is it possible to do the search/replace in-memory without writing the input file to a temp area?

Thanks.

Comment: you always can create String from stream and replace anything, then create stream from this string and pass it to your chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file you are reading is a text file you could:

- convert the byte array you get from step 3 to a string using the string constructor accepting a byte array
- do the search & replace operation on said string using the *replace* or *replaceAll* methods (some regular expression knowledge will be required)
- convert back the result to a byte array with the *getBytes* method
- resume processing from step 4

It is **highly** recommended that you specify the file encoding both in the string constructor and in the getBytes method in order to avoid difficult-to-debug encoding issues.

... and if the file is binary instead... i can't think of a way to search and replace text inside it, sorry.

Comment: You're welcome. Also keep in mind (it came to me only after writing my  answer) that if you're using the *DataInputStream* only for reading a byte array (as the steps you mention seems to do), you might be able to skip completely step 2 and just read the bytes directly from the *FileInputStream* - you only need the former if you need to read primitive "multi-byte" values (int, long, double, char, etc...).